# Use Nginx to proxy to multiple sites under one domain name

Tags: nginx, jenkins, sonarqube

I have a jenkins and sonarqube container running on a server. Is it possible to use Nginx to connect to each under the same domain name? So for example my.domain.com/jenkins hits the jenkins container and my.domain.com/sonar hits sonarqube?

My initial guess at the setup is something like this.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name my.domain.com;


  location /sonar {
    proxy_pass http://sonarqube:9000/;
  }

  location /jenkins {
    proxy_pass http://jenkins:8080/;
  }
}
```

This issues I keep running into involve the subsequent calls made after the initial page. Is there a way to keep the /sonar/ and /jenkins/ piece in all the calls made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make those applications aware of the different context, so that they generate links correctly. For Jenkins you need to specify `--prefix=/jenkins` when starting Jenkins, for SonarQube you need to set up environment variable `SONAR_WEB_CONTEXT=/sonar` when starting SonarQube.

See:

- https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/initial-settings/
- https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/setup/environment-variables/#header-2